# What is the correct way to define and call functions in GNU Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

```
Transcript show: 'Derp'.

printSomething: 'Derpy'.

"The method above produced this error:"
"prog.st:3: expected expression"

printSomething: what
    10 timesRepeat: [
        Transcript show:what.
        Transcript cr.
    ].
```

I'm trying to teach myself Smalltalk now, and I still haven't figured out how to call a function that I've written. I tried to call the function `printSomething` with the parameter `'Derpy'` using the statement `printSomething: 'Derpy'.`, but instead of calling the function, it produced the following error: `prog.st:3: expected expression`.

What am I doing wrong here, and what is the correct way to call functions with parameters in Smalltalk? None of the tutorials that I've read have answered my question so far, and I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: You have a capitalization error in your code. The method name has a capital P, but you're trying to call it with a lowercase p.

Comment: @fzwo Nonetheless, the same error is produced even when the capitalization error has been corrected. I still haven't figured out the correct syntax for Smalltalk function calls.

Comment: For next time, add a tag saying which Smalltalk you're using. GNU Smalltalk and Squeak/Pharo work fairly differently in terms of how they handle source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your errors are twofold:

```
Object class: #Example [
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Smalltalk Examples'
]

Example class extend [
    printSomething: what
        10 timesRepeat: [
            Transcript show:what.
        ]
]

Eval [
    Transcript show: 'Derp'.
    (Example new) printSomething: 'Derpy'.
]
```

Note the `Eval []` block, and that you create an instance of `Example`, not `NameOfSubclass`.

Comment: Which dialects(s) of Smalltalk is this answer relevant to?

Comment: GNU Smalltalk, which matches the syntax of the code the OP linked to.

Answer (score 2):

In which class did you define the method? You're not specifying to which class you're sending the message (telling it to execute the method).

In the case of `Transcript show: 'Derp'.`, you're sending a message to the global variable `Transcript` (an instance of the Stream class), and `show:` is a class method implemented on `Transcript` or one of its superclasses.

If the method is defined on the same class that you're sending from, `self` is the keyword to use, so it would be `self printSomething: 'Derpy'.`

Comment: I did not define the method in a class: is it necessary for all methods in Smalltalk to be defined inside a class?

Comment: Then where/how did you define it? I'm a little rusty, and different Smalltalk environments do certain things (like defining stuff in the workspace) differently, but generally, Smalltalk is very very object-oriented.

Comment: You cannot define functions in Smalltalk, only methods. Also: Transcript is not a class but a global variable holding an instance of Stream class.

Comment: @JohanB Thanks, I've edited my answer to be correct WRT Transcript.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I have no idea how to create or edit classes in ideone, sorry. As Johan said, it is not possible in Smalltalk to define functions, so if you can't create or edit classes in your IDE, you cannot create methods. I guess in that case, ideone is not great for anything that goes beyond calling methods on pre-existing classes' instances (same goes for all other object-oriented languages as well, except that most of them aren't as strictly/cleanly object-oriented as Smalltalk, and do allow functions).

Comment: @fzwo Should Smalltalk methods be defined inside the body of a class ([like this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DTzg8T8T)), or should they be defined elsewhere? I've been trying to call the method from this class, without any success so far.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Smalltalk is usually very tightly integrated with its IDE. In the IDE, there is a thing called a class hierarchy browser (A tree of Classes), where you choose a Class, which has two lists of methods (class methods and instance methods) and lists of variables. Smalltalk does not use text files like other languages. Think of it more object oriented: Each class is an object (actually true in Smalltalk), which has its own properties (methods, etc.). So I can't answer your question. There is no syntax to tell "this method is part of this class", because the class is not a text file.

Comment: Here is a nice image of how a typical class browser looks in a Smalltalk IDE: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xybBn.png

Once you've worked with that, "classical", file-based IDEs will feel very 80s. I don't know why files are not abstracted away more by modern IDEs.

Comment: @JohanB: `double := [:x | x * 2]` defines a function :)

Comment: @FrankShearar true. I should have written global functions, which is what the code excerpt seemed to indicate. I essentially wanted to point out that the printSomething that is noted in the example can only be defined as a method in a class.

Comment: `Smalltalk at: #Double put: [:x | x * 2]` :) I'm just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

Smalltalk is a purely object-oriented language. You can only send messages to objects, which invokes a method defined on their class.

On which class did you define printSomething? If you defined it as an instance method, you need to invoke it on an instance of that class. E.g.:

```
MyClass new printSomething: 'Derpy'
```

If you defined it as a class method, you can send it directly to the class itself.

Comment: Maybe check out Pharo Smalltalk and the excellent online book: www.pharo-project.org. This might help you more, especially for learning Smalltalk in general.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to learn smalltalk, use a smalltalk environment. Don't use a command line interface, don't use an on-line web tool. Both are very useful, but not to learn smalltalk. They don't provide the feedback you need to learn smalltalk good and fast.
*If it doesn't allow you to write most of your code in the debugger, you won't learn smalltalk.*

The book and environment developed to learn smalltalk is [Pharo By Example](http://pharobyexample.org/). Use the image and vm from there. Pharo is developing fast, using a more recent version would be confusing.

Comment: For GNU Smalltalk, the command line interface _is_ a Smalltalk environment! (It's a REPL.)

Comment: Yes. So don't use that to *learn* smalltalk. I also don't recommend topaz to learn smalltalk. Or Amber (yet. Debugger is expected anytime now).

Answer (score 2):

In gnu-smalltalk 3.2.5.

```
Object subclass: Example [
    printSomething: what
    [
        10 timesRepeat: [
            Transcript show:what.
        ]
    ]
]

Eval [
    Transcript show: 'Derp'.
    (Example new) printSomething: 'Derpy'.
]
```